# Sqlite : Modifying locking criteria inside begin - commit

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

As per [sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), when we are using deferred transaction using `begin - commit`, database is locked since the first write.

And most probably this lock is there till the transaction is commited. So If I did `begin` and did the first write, and `commit` comes 180 seconds later, my database is locked till this time.Hence, I cannot do write operations till this time from another thread.

Is there any way that I can tell Sqlite to not hold locks till the `commit` and acquire locks only when its writing within the transaction? So that I have some chances of concurrent writing from another thread during that transaction. Or is there any solution?

I am using `C Sqlite` library in an embedded environment.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing others to write data that you are reading would results in inconsistent data.

To allow a writer and readers at the same time, enable [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).